# Kubuntu 15.04: kquitapp plasma-desktop does not work - why?

Tags: kubuntu, 15.04, kde4, plasma-5

Why does `kquitapp plasma-desktop` result in the following error message?

```
~$ kquitapp plasma-desktop
kquitapp(14021): "Application plasma-desktop could not be found using service org.kde.plasma-desktop and path /MainApplication."
```

I run this command in a terminal emulator with the same user I am logged in as.

I am trying to safely restart plasma desktop, and this is the command recommended in [this forum post](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=118762).

Plasma-related software installed:

```
~$ aptitude search plasma | grep '^i'
i A kdeconnect-plasma               - connect smartphones to your KDE Plasma des
i A kdeplasma-addons-data           - locale files for kdeplasma-addons         
i A libkf5plasma5                   - Plasma Runtime components                 
i A libkf5plasmaquick5              - Plasma Runtime components                 
i A libplasma-geolocation-interface - library for the Plasma geolocation        
i A libplasma-geolocation-interface - Plasma Workspace for KF5 library          
i A libplasma3                      - Plasma Library for the KDE Platform       
i A libplasmaclock4abi4             - library for Plasma clocks                 
i A libplasmagenericshell4          - shared elements for all the plasma shells 
i A plasma-dataengines-addons       - additional data engines for Plasma        
i A plasma-dataengines-workspace    - KDE Plasma data engines                   
i A plasma-desktop                  - Tools and widgets for the desktop         
i A plasma-desktop-data             - Tools and widgets for the desktop data fil
i A plasma-framework                - Plasma Runtime components                 
i   plasma-netbook                  - KDE Plasma workspace for netbook computers
i   plasma-nm                       - Plasma5 networkmanager library.           
i   plasma-runner-telepathy-contact - Telepathy Contact KRunner plugin          
i A plasma-runners-addons           - additional runners for Plasma 5 and Krunne
i A plasma-scriptengine-javascript  - JavaScript script engine for Plasma       
i A plasma-scriptengine-superkaramb - SuperKaramba theme support for the Plasma 
i A plasma-wallpapers-addons        - additional wallpaper plugins for Plasma 5 
i   plasma-widget-folderview        - plasma widget showing the content of a fol
i   plasma-widget-kimpanel          - KIMPanel widget for Plasma                
i   plasma-widget-menubar           - A Plasma applet to display application men
i   plasma-widget-redshift          - Plasma widget for Redshift                
i   plasma-widgets-addons           - additional widgets for Plasma 5           
i A plasma-widgets-workspace        - plasma widgets and containments for the KD
i A plasma-workspace                - Plasma Workspace for KF5                  
i   plasma-workspace-dbg            - Plasma Workspace for KF5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command is too old, use

```
kquitapp plasmashell
```

for killing plasma 5 and then

```
plasmashell
```

for it starting

Comment: Thanks! Is this "officially" documented anywhere?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't remember. I found above solution somewhere at KDE-related forums. Maybe [there](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?66792-Kubuntu-14-10-and-Plasma-5&p=362346&viewfull=1#post362346) or [there](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=289&t=125034#p329702) (point two)